# Passing data between two fragments in two different activities

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to do a very basic example with Fragments.

Structure : **Fragment1 -> Fragment1Activity, Fragment2 -> Fragment2Activity.**

Both activities have a STATIC Fragment in it.

Here are the XMLs:

activity_for_fragment_1.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.xx.fragmentstutorial1.Fragment1"
    tools:context="com.xx.fragmentstutorial1.Fragment1Activity"/>
```

fragment1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_fragment_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.60"
        android:text="This is Fragment 1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_fragment_1_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:text="Type your message here..." >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_fragment_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Me" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_for_fragment_2.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.xx.fragmentstutorial1.Fragment2"
    tools:context="com.xx.fragmentstutorial1.Fragment2Activity"/>
```

fragment_2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_fragment_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="This is Fragment 2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_fragment_2_result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="I will display text from \nFragment 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, I have an Edittext and button in the fragment_1. When I click on the button, I want to get the text entered in EditText and set it to the `textview(textview_fragment_2_result)` in fragment_2

I was able to achieve this, but, I am not very convinced, that the approach I took was good enough. Please look at the java code below..

Fragment1Activity.java

```
public class Fragment1Activity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements Fragment1.ButtonClickListener{

    Fragment1 fragment1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_for_fragment_1);
        System.out.println("onCreate Fragment1Activity");
        fragment1 = (Fragment1) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClick(String message) {
        System.out.println("onButtonClick Fragment1Activity");
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Fragment2Activity.class).putExtra("message", message));
    }

}
```

Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment {

    EditText message;
    Button clickme;

    ButtonClickListener listener;

    public interface ButtonClickListener{
        public void onButtonClick(String message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        if (activity instanceof ButtonClickListener)
            listener = (ButtonClickListener) activity;
        else {

        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        System.out.println("onCreateView Fragment1");

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);

        message = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_fragment_1_text);
        clickme = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_fragment_1);
        clickme.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!message.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    System.out.println("Message in Fragment1 = "+message.getText().toString());

                    listener.onButtonClick(message.getText().toString());
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Please enter some message...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

Fragment2Activity.java

```
public class Fragment2Activity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    Fragment2 fragment2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_for_fragment_2);

        fragment2 = (Fragment2) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_2);
        fragment2.setMessage(getIntent().getExtras().getString("message").toString());
    }

}
```

Fragment2.java

```
public class Fragment2 extends SherlockFragment {

    String msg;
    TextView textview;

    public Fragment2() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, container, false);
        textview = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.textview_fragment_2_result);
        textview.setText(msg);
        return view;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        msg = message;
        textview.setText(msg);
    }
}
```

I have set the text for textview in setMessage() of Fragment2.java, which I think is not a good approach. If i comment that out, I don't see any text in the textview of Fragment2.

Can someone help me out, on how to pass values between two static fragments correctly.

Comment: what you have done is one approach that people use, or else store the value in a shared preference and get it from the second fragment after starting the activity just as you hve

Answer (score 0):

You should go with `interface`

Follow the Diagram Here :

Communication Between Two Fragment is Done Via Activity using Interface

`Fragment` A-------------------------->`Activity`-------------------->`Fragment` B

(defines `Interface`)            (Implement `interface`)              (pass it other Fragment B)

Hope this could help

[Check This Out](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: That is not what i want.. FragmentA -> Activity A -> Activity B -> Fragment B, is what i am looking for..

Answer (score 0):

What you have is mostly good. The part of transferring the data from Fragment1 to Activity1 is good. Once the data gets to Activity2, you are setting it in Fragment2. I would change this part a little.

In Activity2:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_for_fragment_2);

    fragment2 = (Fragment2) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_2);
    fragment2.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
}
```

and in Fragment2.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    String message = bundle.getString("message");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, container, false);
    textview = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.textview_fragment_2_result);
    textview.setText(message);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems correct. The connection between your Fragment1 and Activity1 is just like in the fragments [guideline](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity). Your fragment1 shouldn't know about fragment2 therefore it's OK to pass the responsibility to the fragment's container/parent - activity1 - that knows what to do with the data. This time again your approach is correct - activity1 starts it's slave/child etc. and is responsible to start it with correct data (passed through the intent extras). And then again you have a correct approach - when your activity2 is created you populate it's views with the appropriate content/data (the message) that was meant to be displayed in this activity and given to it by the "parent" activity.